# Adding nodes to tree using postwalk

Tags: clojure

I have a tree with a structure similar to the following:

```
(def tree
  [:ul
   [:li
    [:input]]
   [:li
    [:input]]])
```

I would like to insert a [:button] after each [:input]:

```
[:ul
 [:li
  [:input]
  [:button]]
 [:li
  [:input]
  [:button]]
```

I wrote the following code:

```
 (postwalk
  (fn [x]
    (if (and (vector? x) (= :input (first x)))
      (list x [:button])
      x))
  tree)
```

Which produces:

```
[:ul
 [:li
  ([:input] [:button])]
 [:li
  ([:input] [:button])]]
```

which is *almost* what I want, except that the [:input] and [:button] vectors
are now in a list.

Is there an idiomatic way to "insert" the two nodes without having to put them together into a list?

(Note: Hiccup generates the desired markup with the current result, but I would like to avoid clobbering my trees.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't avoid the list (or a vector) if you do the replacement at the `[:input]` level, because the result of fn will always be a single element. You need the list to contain the two elements.

One alternative would be to do the replacement at the `[:li]` level:

```
(postwalk
  (fn [x]
    (if (and (vector? x) (= :li (first x)) (= :input (ffirst (rest x))))
      (conj x [:button])
      x))
  tree)
```

That's if you really want to avoid the list. In the case of hiccup it works fine with the list, as you said. I wouldn't worry about it.